# Can someone explain intuitively what does 0 mean and unit variance mean?

Tags: normal-distribution, variance, mean

I have read in several article that a Gaussian distribution is called normal if it has 0 mean and unit variance. I don't understand what does it mean and what is the intuition behind it. It would be great if someone can explain in almost layman term.

Comment: What is zero mean?

Comment: The OP is looking at a intuitive feel for what what 0 mean and unit variance is. How can this be a duplicate of the question - 
"What is the difference between normal distribution and standard normal distribution? "

Answer (score 4):

This is also called the standard normal distribution $\mathscr N(0,1)$. The density of this distribution is the "nicest" of the normal family and is the one for wich there are a lot of numerical algorithms for evaluation and PRNG.

There is a useful trick to transform any normal variable to a standard normal:

If $X \sim \mathscr N(\mu, \sigma^2)$, then

$$Z := \frac{X-\mu}\sigma \sim \mathscr N(0, 1)$$
is standard normal.

The density of $Z$ is
$$\varphi(x) = \frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp(-\frac12x^2)$$
whereas the general density formula is
$$\varphi_{\mu,\sigma}(x) = \frac1{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma}}\exp(-\frac1{2\sigma}(x-\mu)^2)$$